# Glide - Could not find the image error in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, thephpleague, android-glide

I have a weird issue with Glide on a fresh local Laravel install (PHP 8.1.13 / Laravel 9.44.0). I followed the documentation to the letter, my route looks like this:

```
Route::get('/img/{path}', [ImageController::class, 'show'])->where('path', '.*');
```

I have an ImageController that looks like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use League\Glide\Responses\LaravelResponseFactory;
use League\Glide\ServerFactory;

class ImageController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Filesystem $filesystem, $path)
    {
        $server = ServerFactory::create([
            'response' => new LaravelResponseFactory(app('request')),
            'source' => $filesystem->getDriver(),
            'cache' => $filesystem->getDriver(),
            'cache_path_prefix' => '.cache',
        ]);

        return $server->getImageResponse($path, request()->all());
    }
}
```

But when I try to access an image through the correct path, it gives me a "Could not find the image storage/images/portrait-rose.jpg." error.

This is the error in laravel.log:

```
[2022-12-24 09:07:18] local.ERROR: Could not find the image `storage/images/gaia.jpg`. {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (League\\Glide\\Filesystem\\FileNotFoundException(code: 0): Could not find the image `storage/images/gaia.jpg`. at C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\league\\glide\\src\\Server.php:629)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\league\\glide\\src\\Server.php(548): League\\Glide\\Server->makeImage('storage/images/...', Array)
#1 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\ImageController.php(20): League\\Glide\\Server->getImageResponse('storage/images/...', Array)
#2 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php(54): App\\Http\\Controllers\\ImageController->show(Object(Illuminate\\Filesystem\\FilesystemAdapter), 'storage/images/...')
#3 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php(43): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('show', Array)
#4 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(260): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\ImageController), 'show')
#5 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(205): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#6 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(798): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#7 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#8 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\AddLinkHeadersForPreloadedAssets.php(19): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#9 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\AddLinkHeadersForPreloadedAssets->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#10 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\inertiajs\\inertia-laravel\\src\\Middleware.php(92): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#11 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(180): Inertia\\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#12 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#13 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#14 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#15 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#17 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#18 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#19 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Session\\Store), Object(Closure))
#20 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#21 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#22 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#23 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#25 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#26 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(799): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#27 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(776): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#28 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(740): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#29 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(729): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(190): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#32 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#35 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#37 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#38 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#39 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#40 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#42 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#43 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#44 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#45 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#46 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#47 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(165): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#48 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(134): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#49 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\public\\index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#50 C:\\wamp\\www\\jolyne\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\resources\\server.php(16): require_once('C:\\\\wamp\\\\www\\\\jol...')
#51 {main}
"}
```

Url is: http://localhost:8000/img/storage/images/portrait-rose.jpg

And if I try to access http://localhost:8000/storage/images/portrait-rose.jpg the image definitely shows up.
What could be the issue there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue is in absolute path of image in url. Try to remove img/ from path in function and you will get an image

Comment: "But when I try to access an image through the correct path" ===> Show relevant code. "it gives me..." ===>>> show the error message in your laravel.log. try to use dd() to dump your variables, to see what's in there

Comment: @UnderDog I edited my post with the laravel.log error message. I don't know what other piece of code I could share other than the route and the controller, glide is (should be) pretty straightforward.

I did try to use dd() to dump my variables but everything looks pretty normal.

Comment: @NIKUNJ KOTHIYA I'm sorry I'm not sure to understand what you mean. If I remove img/ from path, then Glide is not called no?

Comment: Use this code in controller and check it works or not.

public function show(Filesystem $filesystem, $path)
    {
        $server = ServerFactory::create([
            'response' => new LaravelResponseFactory(app('request')),
            'source' => $filesystem->getDriver(),
            'cache' => $filesystem->getDriver(),
            'cache_path_prefix' => '.cache',
            'base_url' => 'img',
        ]);

        return $server->getImageResponse($path, request()->all());
    }

Comment: @NIKUNJ KOTHIYA Nope, still the same :/

Comment: Do you have storage link ? If not then use php artisan storage:link and php artisan optimize:clear.

Comment: @NIKUNJKOTHIYA Yes I did `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: Can you please try with .png extensions files. If it works with .png then there is some issue with .jpg supports.

Comment: You're almost there. The error definitely comes from this line: `return $server->getImageResponse($path, request()->all());` BUT the parameter $path is pasted to your show function. Where did that parameter come from? From the route. First: dd($path), to double check something. Then change your getImageResponse function to `getImageResponse('/' . $path, request()->all());` (see the slash I added?)

Comment: @UnderDog When I dd($path) this is the result: `"storage/images/gaia.jpg" // app\Http\Controllers\ImageController.php:13`

Changing the getImageResponse with the added slash didn't work either :/

Comment: @NIKUNJ KOTHIYA I just tried with a .png file but got the same result.

Comment: @Exoseed There is some issue with the library. We need to find it in the library package.